# Setting a minimum height for a ListView.builder() in flutter

Tags: flutter

So, I have a `CustomScrollView` in flutter, because I am using a `SliverAppBar`. The main scrollable body content is a generated list of widgets, which is generated by `ListView.builder()`. Everything works perfectly, but the problem is, I wish to **set the minimum height of the space that the generated widgets take**. I want to make it so when there aren't enough widgets to take that minimum height, it would just be a whitespace.

I thought of using a `Container` with `constraints`, but it throws and error, that a sliver widget is inside another sliver widget:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minBodyHeight),
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, bottom: 20.0),
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widgetList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => widgetList[index],
        )
      )
    )
  ],
),
```

I then throught to just use a `Column` widget, but when my widget list is very large it takes a lot of time to load:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(),
    SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: minBodyHeight),
        child: widgetList
      )
    )
  ]
)
```

And for that exact reason I want to use `ListView.builder()`. Is there a way using that to set the minimum height for the area that is taken by generated widgets?

Any workarounds will also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ListView.builder() use this property

```
shrinkWrap: true,
```

it controls whether the ListView should adjust its size based on the size of its contents. It is used to determine whether the ListView should take up as much space as it can (when set to false) or only as much space as required by its children (when set to true).

Also set

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: I tried doing that. Yes, when I set `shrinkWrap` to true, it doesn't throw an error.
But then, I can only scroll if I scroll on the padding of the `Container` with the `constraints` and `padding`, if I try to scroll on the area that the `ListView.builder` is taking up, it doesn't let me.

Comment: try to add this too :

physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

its make the scroll withj main scrol widget

Comment: Thank you so much, everything works flawlessly!